# Looping Through Entire Column using Last Row Code

Tags: excel, vba

This might be an obvious question but I have a column with a series of numbers in them. I would like to loop through the entire column to get their values. I'm using this code to find the last row of the column:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
```

How would I be able to get the values starting from the first number in the column to the last?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub loopThroughRange()
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim colRng As Range, rCell As Range
    
    col = 4
    
    ' Option 1: Select from the top to bottom before first blank cell
    Set colRng = Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(1, col).End(xlDown))
    'colRng.Select
    
    ' Option 2: Select from the first value to last value in column (includes blanks)
    'Set colRng = Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp))
    'colRng.Select
    
    For Each rCell In colRng
        Debug.Print rCell.Value
    Next rCell
End Sub
```